# Python Regex for number of times occurences of digit,alphabet

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'm trying to write a regex to validate a token.

`my token has a following structure`:

- 3 or more [0-9] `digits`
- 5 or more [a-z] `small alpha`
- 2 or more [#@] `special characters`
- 5 or more [A-Z] `upper alpha` (optional `?`) may exist or not.

Note: optional [A-Z] characters may exist in some tokens and may not in some and when it exists in token it should be between `5 or more` times.

- token length varies from a `minimum of 6 to a max of 30`

> few examples of valid/invalid matches:

```
token1 : t4xa@ui13p#o6
breakdown : there are 7 [a-z] , 2 special chracter[@#] , 4 digits [0-9]
VALID MATCH: True

token2: 3@piy13Qx9#13@z1337
breakdown: there are 5 [a-z] , 3 special character [@#] , 10 digits [0-9] and 1 [A-Z](which is optional)
VALID MATCH: False (because `[A-Z]` exist in token but it exist for `1` time, it should exist atleast of 5 or more.)

token3: 3@piy1ABC3Qx9#13@DEGFz1337
breakdown: there are 5[a-z], 7 [A-Z] , 10 digits [0-9]
VALID MATCH: True
```

- So far I managed to write a regex to just validate for at least one digit, one uppercase letter, at least one lowercase letter, at least one special character.

```
^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#])[\w\d@#]{6,30}$
```

Comment: Does this part `5 or more [A-Z] upper alpha (optional ?) may exist or not` mean either 0 times or 5 or more times? Is this `3@piy13Qx9#13@z1337` a valid or non valid match?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes either 0 or 5 more times for [A-Z],   yes both examples are a valid match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are either zero or 5 more uppercase chars, then you could use a positive lookahead to assert either no uppercase chars or at least 5 times.

```
(?=(?:[^A-Z\s]*$|(?:[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z]){5})
```

You could use negated character classes and quantifiers to check for the minimum amount of occurrences.

```
^(?=(?:[^\d\s]*\d){3})(?=(?:[^a-z\s]*[a-z]){5})(?=(?:[^@#\s]*[@#]){2})(?=(?:[^A-Z\s]*$|(?:[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z]){5}))[\w\d@#]{6,30}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FQc2WY/1)